# Disabling image compression in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: email, outlook

I have an image attached to an email sent from Yahoo to Microsoft Outlook and Yahoo. The received email displays the image nicely on Yahoo but a lossy version on Outlook. How do I disable the compression?

Answer (score 0):

Does not seems like an Outlook issue. Check the size of the image attachment when you upload it using yahoo mail. Is uploaded image size the same as the one in your disk?

If uploaded image size is smaller, select "Photo size: dont resize" option available at the right side of the attach panel.